# Components of a vector given three points?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I'm trying to begin these two questions (25a and 26a specifically) but am at a loss on where to begin:

[image: vectors]

No information on points on the graphs is given. I know the components of a vector with start- and end-points $P_1(x,y)$ and $P_2(w,z)$ respectively are defined as $\overrightarrow{P_1P_2} = (w-x,z-y)$ but how does this relate to the vectors $w$, $v$, and $u$ as given in the graphs?

Comment: I would assume the grid lines are at integer coordinates, from which you can infer the coordinates of the points.

Comment: $\LaTeX$ note - use
    \overrightarrow{AB}
for $\overrightarrow{AB}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Recall that $ \overrightarrow{p_1p_2} +  \overrightarrow{p_2p_3} +  \overrightarrow{p_3p_4} =  \overrightarrow{p_1p_4}$
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is often to think of the coordinates of a vector as
$$
\text{"coordinates of the tip"} - \text{"coordinates of the tail"}
$$
Following this convention in part (a) we have
\begin{align*}
\mathbf u &= \langle 5,-5\rangle-\langle0,0\rangle & 
\mathbf v &= \langle -5,-3\rangle-\langle5,-5\rangle & 
\mathbf w &= \langle-2,5\rangle-\langle-5,-3\rangle \\
&=\langle5,-5\rangle &&=\langle-10,2\rangle &&=\langle3,8\rangle
\end{align*}
Thus
$$
\mathbf u+\mathbf v+\mathbf w=\langle5,-5\rangle+\langle-10,2\rangle+\langle3,8\rangle=\langle-2,5\rangle
$$
How does this sum relate to the picture? Can you use this to do part (b) and #26?